# How to have chapter appendices labelled A,B,C... and retain chapter numbering?

Tags: numbering, appendices

I'm writing a thesis (using the book format on Latex), and some of my chapters happen to have appendixes. I would like each appendix to be numbered A, B, and so on, so I used the following code for each one of them:

```
\appendix
\section*{Appendix} 
\setcounter{theorem}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{A.\arabic{theorem}}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{A.\arabic{equation}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{A.\arabic{subsection}}
```

The problem is now all chapters are numbered with A, instead of using progressive arabic numbers...how can I limit the counters (and the reset of figure and table numbers) to the appendix section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not create a `theorem` environment (and didn't load any packages to do so), so I commented the line adding the `theorem` counter to the list of counters to be redefined. If you need any more counters add them to the `\Appendix@CounterList`, just make sure to comment all the line endings to prevent adding a spurious space to any of the names. An empty list item is detected, so adding a completely empty element does no harm (so the comma after the last entry in the comma separated list is ok), while an element containing of a space wouldn't be detected.

Adding `\appendix` to the environment doesn't work out, because it does some redefinitions globally, the only alternative would be to save all the globally redefined macros in temporary ones and resetting them. Ask if you need this, I could add that (in a static manner or by redefining `\gdef`---which might be a bad idea). However the following might be a good start:

**EDIT:** I've added the numbering of appendix sections. Also I've added code which is able to undo any changes made by a `\appendix` (I hope). The relevant lines in the creation of `Appendix` (the environment) are commented, since I don't think it makes much sense adding `\appendix` as the changes made by it seem all to be not necessary with the section-approach.

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{duckuments}

\newcounter{appendixcounter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\Appendix@Counter[1]
  {%
    \Appendix@SaveCounter{#1}%
    \setcounter{#1}{0}%
    \expandafter\Appendix@SaveTheCounter\expandafter{#1}%
  }
\newcommand*\Appendix@SaveTheCounter[1]
  {%
    \expandafter\def\csname the#1\endcsname{\Alph{appendixcounter}.\arabic{#1}}%
  }
\newcommand*\Appendix@SaveCounter[1]
  {%
    \expandafter\edef\csname Appendix@SaveCounter@#1\endcsname{\arabic{#1}}%
  }
\newcommand*\Appendix@ResetCounter[1]
  {%
    \setcounter{#1}{\csname Appendix@SaveCounter@#1\endcsname}%
  }
\newcommand*\Appendix@CounterList
  {%
    %theorem,%
    equation,%
    figure,%
    table,%
  }
\newcommand*\Appendix@CounterOnlyResetList
  {%
    chapter,%
    section,%
  }
\newcommand*\Appendix@GlobalUndoList
  {%
    thechapter,%
    @chapapp,%
  }
\newcommand*\Appendix@GlobalSave[1]
  {%
    \expandafter\Appendix@GlobalSave@i\expandafter{\csname #1\endcsname}{#1}%
  }
\newcommand*\Appendix@GlobalSave@i[2]
  {%
    \expandafter\let\csname Appendix@GlobalSave@#2\endcsname=#1%
  }
\newcommand*\Appendix@GlobalRestore[1]
  {%
    \expandafter\Appendix@GlobalRestore@i\expandafter
      {\csname Appendix@GlobalSave@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
  }
\newcommand*\Appendix@GlobalRestore@i[2]
  {%
    \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname #2\endcsname=#1%
  }
\newcommand*\Appendix@DoForListMacro[2]
  {%
    \expandafter\@for\expandafter\zz\expandafter:\expandafter=\expandafter
      {#1}\do
      {%
        \if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\zz}\relax
        \else
          #2%
        \fi
      }%
  }
\newcommand*\Appendix@DoForCounterList
  {%
    \Appendix@DoForListMacro{\Appendix@CounterList}%
  }
\newcommand*\Appendix@DoForGlobalUndoList
  {%
    \Appendix@DoForListMacro{\Appendix@GlobalUndoList}%
  }
\newcommand*\Appendix@DoForCounterOnlyResetList
  {%
    \Appendix@DoForListMacro{\Appendix@CounterOnlyResetList}%
  }
\newenvironment{Appendix}
  {%
    \Appendix@DoForCounterList{\Appendix@Counter{\zz}}%
    \Appendix@DoForCounterOnlyResetList{\Appendix@SaveCounter{\zz}}%
    %\Appendix@DoForGlobalUndoList{\Appendix@GlobalSave{\zz}}%
    %\appendix
    \refstepcounter{appendixcounter}%
    \section*{Appendix \Alph{appendixcounter}}%
  }
  {%
    \Appendix@DoForCounterList{\Appendix@ResetCounter{\zz}}%
    \Appendix@DoForCounterOnlyResetList{\Appendix@ResetCounter{\zz}}%
    %\Appendix@DoForGlobalUndoList{\Appendix@GlobalRestore{\zz}}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\blindduck[1,maths]
\begin{equation}
  E=mc^2
\end{equation}
\begin{Appendix}
  \blindduck[1,maths]
  \begin{figure}% >>>
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%
    \caption{A friendly duck\label{fig:duck}}%
  \end{figure}% <<<
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
      Ducks&are&friendly
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{The truth\label{tab:truth}}
  \end{table}
\end{Appendix}
\begin{equation}
  E=mc^2
\end{equation}
\chapter{Bar}
\blindduck[1,maths]
\begin{Appendix}
  \blindduck[1,maths]
\end{Appendix}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Now chapter numbering is finally retained. The only thing that is not working yet is that all appendices are labelled with A, instead of having A, B, C, and so on; probably I'm doing something wrong, but I don't understand what it is

Comment: @Maria that is my fault, as I did not include a counter for the appendices. I thought you wanted all of them be labelled with `A`. How do you want them to be labelled? Should those appendices be sections or chapters?

Comment: They should be sections; basically the last section of chapter 2 of my thesis is an appendix, and it should be labelled A; the last section of chapter 3 is an appendix as well, and should be labelled B

Comment: @Maria I'll post some stuff in a minute.

Comment: @Maria see my edit, I hope it adds everything you need.